# Tool for converting JPGs to PDFs, and resizing PDFs

Tags: pdf, file-converter

I have a ton (!) of multi-page documents that need to be converted to PDF from JPGs. I also need to re-size PDFs that are way larger than they need to be.

Looking for fast, efficient, and reasonable cost. Any recommendations on software?

Comment: Linux / cygwin variant? jpegtopnm , pnmtops, ps2pdf? Gimp ? Irfanview?

Comment: For which operating system?

Comment: The multi-page documents are JPG files, one image per page, all stored in a folder per document?

Answer (score 1):

I think Acrobat Pro (the paid program, not the free Reader) will do this.  It certainly has the size reduction.

You may find that you can get even better size reduction by using Compress-or-Die (compressordie.com) and converting jpeg to png.  If they are jpegs of text this should work quite a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

To solve a requirement like yours, I recommend using Foxit PhantomPDF.

This application can easily convert many file formats, including jpg. To do this, simply specify the folder where the images are stored, select them individually or multiselect them as desired, as shown in the following picture:

[image]

Also, pdfs can be resized as below:

[image]

Obviously, resizing can also be done individually, by changing a series of parameters:

[image]

As you can see, the application is fast, efficient, and I think, for a ton of features, it has a reasonable cost (for about $ 160 we paid for the *Business* version we received five activation keys).

Answer (score 0):

One good program for working with PDFs is Adobe Acrobat. If you have access to Adobe Acrobat on your computer then that would be a good way to go.
Here is a guide that I found explaining how to convert a JPEG to PDF using Adobe Acrobat:

http://smallbusiness.chron.com/convert-jpeg-pdf-using-acrobat-47188.html

As for resizing pages, Adobe Acrobat has a tool called Organize Pages where there are several ways you can resize your documents. (See image below)

[image: Adobe Acrobat Organize Pages Tool]

However, if you don't have Adobe Acrobat then you might want to go with another solution that doesn't require a paid subscription.

Hope this helps!